# Is it possible to combine Guava's ForwardingListIterator with a PeekingIterator?

Tags: java, list, collections, iterator, guava

I want to use Guava to implement a "peekable" `ListIterator` that lets me peek at the previous and next list elements without moving the cursor.  This is akin to Guava's [`PeekingIterator`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/PeekingIterator.html), only bidirectional because Guava's `PeekingIterator` only has a [`next()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/PeekingIterator.html#next%28%29) method, not a [`previous()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingListIterator.html#previous%28%29).

Does this need to be implemented by writing a new `PeekingListIterator` class or is there an Guava-intended way to combine the two concepts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Where's the value in introducing a new "peeking" concept to an iterator that's already easily scrollable in both directions?

If you really want it, you could just implement two trivial static helpers:

```
public static <T> T peekNext(ListIterator<T> iterator) {
  T next = iterator.next();
  iterator.previous();
  return next;
}

public static <T> T peekPrevious(ListIterator<T> iterator) {
  T previous = iterator.previous();
  iterator.next();
  return previous;
}
```

Comment: So are you saying that the answer to the question is that there is no way to combine the two without rolling my own `PeekingListIterator`?  You could easily ask the same "what's the value" question about the `PeekingIterator`, but apparently someone saw the value in it, but for some reason omitted `PeekingListIterator`.

Comment: You can't move an `Iterator` backwards, but you can move a `ListIterator` backwards.  Therefore `PeekingIterator` provides functionality that can't be replicated with a normal `Iterator`, but every `ListIterator` can be used to get the same functionality of a `PeekingListIterator`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman that's a very good point +1.  So the to answer Kevin's question directly, the value is in the intelligibility of the client code in this scenario.  From a client perspective, `next = iterator.peekAtNext()` is easier understood than `next = iterator.next(); iterator.previous();`.

Comment: And in that case, you just do peekNext(iterator) with Kevin's method, which isn't that bad.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks; that is exactly what I was trying to say.

Comment: @glenviewjeff: Please don't edit to change the *meaning* of post, as you did here. You removed a very salient question.